# Unable to customise the build directory for Qt Creator/qmake

Tags: qt, build-process

I've got problem trying to specify the build directory (the directory that is to store all the files prior to copying them to the DESTDIR path).

I've got the following values in my .pro file:

```
DESTDIR  = E:/Development/project/build/core/debug
OUT_PWD  = E:/Development/project/build/core/debug
OBJECTS_DIR = $$DESTDIR/.obj
MOC_DIR = $$DESTDIR/.moc
RCC_DIR = $$DESTDIR/.qrc
UI_DIR = $$DESTDIR/.ui
```

Now, all the files eventually end up in that location, however during build, the compiler is always using the "E:/Development/build/MinGW_32bit-Debug/src/core" folder (note the missing project path). This is annoying, because I want to use the /Project/build directory as this location (which is not tracked in my git repo).

Ideally, I'd like this path to be: `E:\Development\project\build\src\core\debug`.

The reason I want to do this is that the build process has the same location to include the compiled libs from (it's a subdirs project).

I've had a look in the `Tools > Options > Build & Run > General` settings, and the default build directory is: `build/build-%{CurrentProject:Name}-%{CurrentKit:FileSystemName}-%{CurrentBuild:Name}`

I've had a look in my project.pro.user file, and found the following line:

```xml
<value type="QString" key="ProjectExplorer.BuildConfiguration.BuildDirectory">E:/Development/build/MinGW_32bit-Debug</value>
```

However I'm unable to change this value. If I edit this line in the file directly, as soon as I open Qt Creator again, the change has reverted back.

Is this a Qt Creator thing, or is it a qmake thing? Would I better off using a different build system such as CMake?

Comment: Go to the `Project` tab on the grey toolbar at the left of the screen. Make sure your project's tab is selected. Select the `Build & Run` subtab. Select the MinGW kit if it isn't selected by default. Select the `Build` subtab. The build directory is there for editing by you.

Comment: Ahh, so that's where it lives. Strange that editing the .user file directly has no effect, but I'll modify it in there :)

Comment: Editing the `.user` file has effect, but it has to be done when the project is not open in Qt Creator. The `.user` file is just storage for Creator's project setting. It is not used by qmake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The build directory is "specified" by starting `qmake` or `cmake` in the build directory. There's no point to setting it in the `.pro` file itself.

Qt Creator stores the build directories for a project in the `.user` file. Any changes made to this file outside of Qt Creator, while the project is open in the Creator, will be lost. Creator loads the file when opening the project, or creates a new one if it doesn't exist.

When the Creator starts the build by invoking `qmake` or `cmake`, it starts that process in the build directory. That's also how you should be building the project manually from the command line.

Finally, it makes very little sense to override the destinations of the intermediate build results. They are somewhere within the build directory, and that's all that matters. You're not using these files directly for anything anyway.

The customary way to build a qmake project:

```
mkdir project-build
cd project-build
qmake ~/project-src
make -j
```

The build folder should not be within the source tree!

I've recently started keeping them in `$TEMP` / `%TEMP%`: manually purging the stale builds of all sort of test projects got old after a while :)

Comment: Thanks, I manually added the 'OBJECTS_DIR' options to file to see if that made a difference, but I need to set the build dir as mentioned in the comment above.

Comment: Also, I do want to have the build directory within my project directory (my src dir is a sub directory of my project directory, and a sibling to build), but the entire build directory is excluded from git, and is never committed to the repo. This ensure's that all project related code and compiled files are within the actual project folder :)

Comment: `The build folder should not be within the source tree!` Why? Do you have a reference for this? With other build systems and IDEs, it's a pretty common setup to have e.g. a `build` folder as a subdirectory (which gets `.gitignore`d of course).

Comment: The reference is IMHO called "common sense". Just because ancient Visual Studio did it, and - sadly - continues to do it, doesn't mean that there's any reason for it. Source code could be on a CD and be read only, for all I know. There's no reason to write to source code folder. In fact, in large and complex builds, there can be subtle buildsystem bugs that may produce unreproducible builds because some junk gets written to the source folder. When I do CI builds, I do a shallow git checkout into a tempfs that gets set read-only before the build. On my dev machine, builds are in temp folder.